# Gather all column names into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project whos purpose is to rename all table names and column names in the sql database from one language to another. I have gather all the local table names into a table ltbl_TableNames and want to add all the columns of these tables into a table called ltbl_TableColumns.

I also want every table column to have a link to their table name. For example, the table 'Sales' have a column named 'Sum'. The table 'Sales' has the ID '10000'. I want to add that ID in a column named 'TableName_ID' for linking purposes. Is this possible to do without a lot of hassle?

Disclaimer: I am thinking about the renaming process. I only want to gather the column names with link to their parent table name.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: All table names and all columns :) The only viable way I see is Visual Studio + SSDT -> Refactor -> Rename object. Depending on complexity(table/views/stored procedure) it could be multiple changes per single column and you are trying to rename everything - https://the.agilesql.club/2016/09/refactoring-in-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt/

Comment: The renaming process of things aren't my side of the business. I only want to gather the columns in a table with link to their parent table name. Everything else is fixed by someone else. )

Comment: Simply query [sys.tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) metadata tables

Comment: All tables and all their columns are already enumerated in INFORMATION SCHEMA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Why repeating it?

Comment: A little bit for practice sake, and also I didn't know that heh. Does the Information Schema tell what table the different columns are a part of?

Comment: yes. it does. Please check out the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please provide some input and expected output for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sys.tables` for getting list of `table name` in your database.
Similarly for `column name` you may use `information_schema.columns` as this will give records with `table name`. 
From the above 2 records you can easily make you required result.

```
            ;WITH CTABLE AS 
        ( SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE TYPE_DESC = 'USER_TABLE' )
        , COLUMNNAME AS 
        ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS )
        SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE FROM 
        (SELECT CTABLE.NAME AS TABLENAME , COLUMNNAME.COLUMN_NAME, COLUMNNAME.COLUMN_NAME + '_' + CAST(CTABLE.OBJECT_ID AS VARCHAR(15)) AS NEW_COLUMNNAME   
        FROM CTABLE INNER JOIN COLUMNNAME ON CTABLE.NAME = COLUMNNAME.TABLE_NAME ) AS D
```

You may try this for your result.